# Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error:

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

Also when I use other MySQLi functions it gives me the same error but for that function.

My `connection.php`:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  trigger_error('Connection failed: '.$mysqli->error);
}

?>
```

My function:

```
function form_year($find, $value, $from, $vehicletype){
    //Query setup
    $autoquery = "SELECT    
                        Year, 
                        Vehicle, 
                        Brand, 
                        Model, 
                        Type, 
                    FROM 
                        vehicle_tbl
                    WHERE
                        Vehicle = '".$vehicletype."'
                    GROUP BY
                        Year";
    $autoresult = $mysqli->query($autoquery);

    $search = array("%value%", "%options%");
    $rows = file_get_contents("tpl/options.html");
    while($row = $autoresult->fetch_assoc()){
        $replace = array($row[$value], $row[$value]);
        $tr .= str_replace($search, $replace, $rows);
    }
    return str_replace($find, $tr, $from);
}
```

Function and connection is included where the function is called

Comment: Your function does not have `$mysqli` in scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick/dirty fix:

```
  function form_year($find, $value, $from, $vehicletype){
    //Query setup
    global $mysqli;
    $autoquery = "SELECT  [...]
```

Comment: The problem with global is that it doesn't verify the variable you're using. So if you call your function before the connection to your database has been made, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to delete the comma after `Type` as this might be a syntax error for the MySQL string. Also try to echo `$mysqli->error` and look what it says.

Comment: Ah thats just because I editted the table names and forgot that comma there :P But thanks! The answer above helped

Answer (score 1):

Your `$mysqli` object is in global scope, not in the scope of the function.  You should pass the `mysqli` object to the function as a parameter such that you have access to it. So something like this:

```
function form_year($find, $value, $from, $vehicletype, $db){
    ...
    $autoresult = $db->query($autoquery);
    ...
}
```

Note I would also add some validation in the function to make sure a proper mysqli object was passed, but that is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You got to make sure that your $mysqli is available in scope(which is not the case in your function). A few solution available: global, passing in arguments, singleton. Personnaly I usually do singleton for my database connection, something like that:

```
class DB {
private static $_instance;

public static function get() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","db");
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            trigger_error('Connection failed: '.self::$_instance->error);
        }
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
}

//Calling

$autoresult = DB::get()->query($autoquery);
```