# Call to a member function query on a non-object

Tags: php

I receive this Fatal Error when working with objects in PHP:

> Call to a member function query() on a non-object

index.php:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", "root", "xxx");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$conn = new Connection($db);

$data = $conn->getCities();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

connection.php:

```
class Connection {

    protected $db;

    public function _construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getCities() {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM city"); \\ Error here
    }
}
```

In a single file it works fine:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", "root", "xxx");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM city");

foreach($data as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

What is it about the object orientation I'm not understanding, or is there another reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of Call to a member function query() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14573076).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code snippet is a copy/paste and is completely accurate, then you may have a very simple typo in the constructor. In PHP, they must start with two underscores in a row, and your code has only one:

```
class Connection {
    public function _construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

should become

```
class Connection {
    public function __construct(PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

The explanation is this: Your existing code contains no syntactical or even semantic errors. There is simply a method called `_construct` that never gets called. When you make the new object, is is constructing the object, passing in a never-used `$db` that gets silently ignored.

Comment: I was wondering about the use of `(PDO $db)` in the definition. Is that legal?

Comment: @ethrbunny That is called type hinting http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php and is perfectly legal. If user attempts to make a call with any object other than type `PDO` it will raise an error.