# Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, database-connection

I am trying to get php to simplify my database connections so that I can modify one area of the code and effect the entire program. Here is what I have:

**PAGE: rdpa.php (A modules page**

```
/**************************/
/* Create System Settings */
/**************************/

/* Database Connection Settings */
$_SESSION['servername']     = "localhost";
$_SESSION['mysql_username'] = "username";
$_SESSION['mysql_password'] = "password";
$_SESSION['dbname']         = "mydb";

//Turn on Error Report. True = On / False = Off
//ErrorReporting(false);

//Display Error.kfkg
function ErrorReporting($ErrOn){
if ($ErrOn == true) {
    //Show Error
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);
}
}

/**************************************
Open Database Connection Function.
***************************************/

class db_class {

function db_conn() {

    global $conn;
    global $mysqli;
    $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    // Test if connection succeeded
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . 
             mysqli_connect_error() . 
             " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
        }

    //return db_conn;
    }

}
```

PAGE: testdb3.php

```
<?php

//Included file.
include 'modules/rdpa.php';

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Access our class.
$db_Class = new db_Class;
$conn = ($db_Class->db_conn());

//connect to the database.
$sql = "SELECT id, region FROM tbl_region;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<td width="1"><label for="delete">
<input type="radio" name="region" id="region" value="'.$row["id"].'">
</label></td>';

        echo '<td align="left" valign="top"><p>'.$row["region"].'</p></td></tr>';
    }
}


?>
```

When I run testdb3.php I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\websites\rdpa\testdb3.php on line 15

This is Line 15:

```
//connect to the database.
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Can some please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try this
 comment these two line  $db_Class = new db_Class;
$conn = ($db_Class->db_conn());

Comment: please return your connection object your problem will solved from  db_conn function return your $conn variable

Comment: It returns the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in testdb3.php on line 15 Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in testdb3.php on line 15

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function query() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573076/call-to-a-member-function-query-on-a-non-object)

Comment: Like this:

class db_class {
 
 function db_conn() {
 
  global $conn;
  global $mysqli;
  $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);
  
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  
  return $conn;
  return $mysqli;
 }

}

Comment: Abp not sure I understand what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: @FrankG. return `$conn` from function `db_conn()` it will solve your problem

Comment: Please first check you connection with db is connected or not please first print no_rows return from db because  i checked in my local it return num_rows so please print it then try,

Comment: Abp I returned $conn an still errors here:

class db_class {
 
 function db_conn() {
 
  global $conn;
  global $mysqli;
  $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);
  
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  
  return $conn;
 }

}

Comment: Dinesh Bhojvani, I know it works because when I combine both rdpa.php code into the testdb3 it returns values. So something between the inserted page rdpa.php and testdb3 is failing or not getting across. Here is the link of both combined to show you it returns db values http://rdparisi.com/rdpatrium/testdb.php

Comment: Dinesh that testdb.php page has this code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **rdpa.php** page to

```
class db_class {

    function db_conn() {

        global $conn;
        global $mysqli;
        $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

            // Test if connection succeeded
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("Database connection failed: " .
                                mysqli_connect_error() .
                                " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
                );
            }
        }
        return $conn;       //return connection string
    }

}           //this is missing in your code
```

You need to return connection string from function. Right now you are returning `$conn` in `if` loop i.e. if error occurred then return connection this is what you are doing.

Please use some IDE to code. `}` for `class` is missing in your code

Comment: Thank you that did it. Simple things sometimes can make life soooooo HARD :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issues with semicolon after query end.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, region FROM tbl_region;"; your current query please replace with below query which i have given below. may it helps you.
$sql = "SELECT id, region FROM tbl_region";
```

try above query it will solve your issues. and also replace your function code you haven't return conn object. replace with below code. your problem will solved.

```
function db_conn() {

    global $conn;
    global $mysqli;
    $conn = new mysqli($_SESSION['servername'], $_SESSION['mysql_username'], $_SESSION['mysql_password'], $_SESSION['dbname']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    // Test if connection succeeded
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . 
             mysqli_connect_error() . 
             " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
        }


    }
return $conn;
}
```

Comment: Hello Dinesh, I tried removing the inside ; ($sql = "SELECT id, region FROM tbl_region";) but it still tossing that error. Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in... line 15.

Comment: I replaced the function above but now I get no error or nothing on the page. Just a blank page.